# how to check if NSString = a specific string value?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

Hi I am woundering if you can check to see if a NSString equals a specific value say for instance a name of a person?

I am thinking along the lines of

```
if (mystring == @"Johns"){
    //do some stuff in here
}
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
if ([mystring isEqualToString:@"Johns"]){
    //do some stuff in here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another method you might want to use in some circumstances:

```
NSArray * validNames = @[ @"foo" , @"bar" , @"bob" ];

if ([validNames indexOfObject:myString].location != NSNotFound) 
{
    // The myString is one of the names in the valid names array
}
```

Or if you have a large amount of names in the array you could use a [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/containsObject:), since finding an object is faster than in an array (`(O(Log N)` vs `O(N)`)

```
NSSet * validNamesSet = [NSSet setWithArray:validNames];

if ([validNamesSet containsObject:myString]) 
{
    // This is faster than indexOfObject for large sets
}
```

These methods work because `NSSet` and `NSArray` use [`isEqual:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) which will call [`isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:) for `NSString` instances.

Comment: When would you want to use the `location` approach as opposed to a for loop with the `isEqualToString` method?

Comment: @Pavan Its a little easier to use `indexOfObject` than a for loop (fewer lines of code).  Other than that there is little difference.  The NSSet method can be faster than looping though an array for large sets, but for most cases it will not be significant.