# PFQueryTableViewController: How to dequeue cell for identifier depending upon contents of objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

**Scenario** = I have a PFQTVC that I am using as a messenger. When the table queries for the objects there is a key called "senderID". I want to check if the "senderID" is equal to the current user's ID, and if it is, then the table will dequeue for a cell that displays the current user's information on the *right* side of the cell - and if it is **not** equal to the current user's ID, then dequeue for a cell that has the other user's information on the *left* (like in an instant messenger). I use this code inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    MessagesTableViewCell *cell;

    NSString *userID = [PFUser currentUser][@"userID"];
    NSString *senderID = object[@"senderID"];

    NSLog(@"userID = %@", userID);
    NSLog(@"senderID = %@",senderID);

    //I believe the problem is here
    if (userID == senderID) {

        NSLog(@"CELL RIGHT");

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"CELL LEFT");

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
    }
```

**Problem** = When I run my code in this manner, it just logs out

[image]

Thing is I don't think that the **if statement** is working. But this is exactly how everyone I here online tells me how to do it. You can clearly see in the Debug that the "senderID" IS in fact equal to the "userID". But the if statement keeps saying that it is false and executing the "else" block.

Seems to me it should have still dequeued for the "CELL RIGHT" cell either way because you can tell in the debug that there was intact a different userID getting called when I scroll down. (see "HERE" in the picture)

**Question** = Does anyone know who to get the if statement working right so I can dequeue for a different type cell depending upon if the object's "senderID" equals the current user's ID? If anyone can help I will love you forever.

**What I've tried** = Before all you guys start commenting with different ways for me to write the same thing, here are all of the ways I've tried to get this to work and it still fails.

```
if (object[@"senderID"]==[PFUser currentUser][@"userID"])

if ([object objectForKey:@"senderID"]==[[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"userID"])
```

Comment: Check this for comparing strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266218/how-to-check-if-nsstring-a-specific-string-value

Answer (score 0):

@Fosco was right. I needed to check isEqualToString:. I kind of feel stupid...