# See NSTask output Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

How could I make an if statement that's like:

```
if(the output of a nstask is equal to a specific string){
   //do stuff over here
}
```

I'm running a `NSTask` and it put's out the data that's coming from it in the NSLog, but how could I not show it there but store it as a NSString or something like that

This is what my task looks like

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/csrutil"];
[task setArguments:@[ @"status" ]];
[task launch];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `pipe` and a `file handle` to read the result.

Write a method

```
- (NSString *)runShellScript:(NSString *)cmd withArguments:(NSArray *)args
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:cmd];
    [task setArguments:args];

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

and call it

```
NSString *result = [self runShellScript:@"/usr/bin/csrutil" withArguments:@[ @"status" ]];
```

Comment: thanks for the help but how could I make an if statement if result is equal to a string?

Comment: [How to check if NSString equals a specific string value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7266218) @Bisquitue

Comment: @JoshCaswell That was a stupid question I just realized it after I posted it